# How do I prevent 'open handles' issues when using the Solana 'Connection' object?

Tags: web3.js, typescript

I am using Solana and Solana SPL in TypeScript with Jest, running integration tests with `solana-test-validator` running.

Whenever I do `await connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner()` or `await connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner()` in my tests, Jest complains:

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  TCPWRAP

      237 |   test(`Can find Bob's USDC account from his regular account`, async () => {
      238 |     let parsedTokenAccountsByOwner =
    > 239 |       await connection.getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner(bob.publicKey, {
          |                        ^
      240 |         mint: mintAccountPublicKey,
      241 |       });
```

I obviously need to close the open TCP handle, but how do I do this? I tried looking for a `connection.close()` or similar (that I could run `afterAll()` my tests) but haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly because the `Connection` class, by default, creates a long-lived HTTP Agent. Wherever you create the `Connection` instance in your tests, disable it.

```
const connection = new Connection('https://...', {httpAgent: false});
```